# jvisualvm connect to remote jstatd not showing applications

Tags: java, jvm, jvisualvm, jstatd

I started a `jstatd` on the remote server (Ubuntu Server 14.04):

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=.jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalltrue -p 9099
```

and try to connect to it with jvisualvm on windows. I checked `netstat`, the connection is established, and on the remote it logs the call:

```
Sep 11, 2015 12:48:51 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.82.199.0: [10.82.199.0: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: java.rmi.Remote lookup(java.lang.String)]
Sep 11, 2015 12:48:55 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.82.199.0: [10.82.199.0: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: java.rmi.Remote lookup(java.lang.String)]
Sep 11, 2015 12:48:59 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.82.199.0: [10.82.199.0: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: java.rmi.Remote lookup(java.lang.String)]
```

All signs are saying that it's working. but however no applications is showing in jvisualvm:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Apparently VisualVM expects a consistent DNS name for the server you're trying to connect to remotely (the Ubuntu Server 14.04 in your case). Hence, if you're specifying an **IP address instead of a DNS name** to VisualVM you should add the following to your jstatd startup line:

```
-J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<the IP address to your Ubuntu server here>
```

**Additionally**, I found out that specifying **the port option** (-p 9099 in your case) is **not supported** in some VisualVM releases:

> **Known limitation:** In this VisualVM release the jstatd's default port and rminame must be used when starting the jstatd utility, i.e. the use of the -p and -n options is not supported.
>   [VisualVM Troubleshooting Guide](http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html?Java_VisualVM)

All in all, **you should try** running the following jstatd line on your Ubuntu Server:

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=.jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.82.83.117 -J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalltrue
```

**Sources**:

1. http://www.catify.com/2012/09/26/remote-monitoring-with-visualvm/
2. It worked for me :)

Comment: adding the IP address as the hostname option fixed the issue for me. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just in case that someone is having problems with the command above, the parameter "-J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalltrue" should be "-J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true".

Answer (score 2):

```
jstatd -p 1099 -J-Djava.rmi.sver.hostname=10.250.105.112 -J-Djava.security.policy=<(echo 'grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {permission java.security.AllPermission;};')
```

Works for Me Perfectly

Comment: In JDK 11 tools.jar is replaced with modules. You'll want to explore `jrt:/jdk.jstatd`.

Comment: Should java.rmi.sver.hostname be java.rmi.server.hostname ?

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else...

I was running into problems where neither `jstatd` nor adding a plain JMX connection in VisualVM worked. The former would not give any error messages, it just wouldn't list any apps. The latter would give me an error saying `"Cannot connect to some-server:30648 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://some-server:30648/jmxrmi`.

Trying to use the excellent sjk-plus tool to manually connect to the JMX service gave the following error:

```sh
$ java --add-opens java.base/jdk.internal.perf=ALL-UNNAMED \
       --add-opens jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach=ALL-UNNAMED \
       -Dsjk.breakCage=false \
       -jar scripts/sjk-plus-0.14.jar 
       mx --get --allMatched -b com.acme.some.package:name=* -f Count \
      -s some-server:30648
JMX Connection failed: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.1.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Do you see it? *127.0.1.1*, what is that weird IP address doing there?

This was caused by a particular entry in the `/etc/hosts` file on the server:

```sh
user@some-server:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   some-server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Changing the `some-server` entry in the `hosts` file and restarting the process made it work with `sjk-plus`, and made it discoverable with `jstatd` as well.

Answer (score 0):

in java 11+

```
jstatd -J-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true \
    -J-Djava.security.policy=.jstatd.all.policy \
    -J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true \
    -J-Djava.security.policy=<(echo 'grant codebase "jrt:/jdk.jstatd" {permission java.security.AllPermission;}; grant codebase "jrt:/jdk.internal.jvmstat" {permission java.security.AllPermission;};')
```